# From which version does httpclient get supported in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Someone recommend us to use HttpClient rather than HttpWebRequest in the code. I am wondering from which version does HttpClient get supported?

I searched, 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx

Does it only from 4.5?

Comment: Be aware that `HttpClient` is built using `HttpWebRequest`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only supported in .NET 4.5.

However, it is available for .NET 4 as part of the Web API, including the [source code](http://wcf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/417c9a96fc24#WCFWebApi/Http/Src/Microsoft.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs)
 of via [a NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/HttpClient).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a new class in Framework 4.5

> > HttpClient
>
> A new class called HttpClient has been added to make working with HTTP
>   requests much easier. For more info, see Making apps social and
>   connected with HTTP services and.

[What's New in Windows Communication Foundation 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789.aspx)